# How to do this vb 2010

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
Int32 number = new Random().Next();
Console.WriteLine(number);

Func<Int32> GenerateRandom = delegate() { return new Random().Next(); };

Console.WriteLine("Begin Call");
GenerateRandom.DoAsync(number => Console.WriteLine(number));
Console.WriteLine("End Call");
```

Comment: Are you just trying to convert the c# code to vb.net code?

Comment: Just compile it in a language you know then use Reflector to view it in whatever language you want.

Comment: Before you spend too much translating: [Why is Random giving the same results every time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c)

Comment: There seems to be a battle of the code converters going on here.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what the typical automated converters come up with for that.  Function lamdas were already supported in VS2008, takes some smarts to convert an anonymous method though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim number As Int32 = New Random().[Next]()
Console.WriteLine(number)

Dim GenerateRandom As Func(Of Int32) = Function() New Random().[Next]()

Console.WriteLine("Begin Call")
GenerateRandom.DoAsync(Function(number) Console.WriteLine(number))
Console.WriteLine("End Call")
```

Comment: This was generated using the tool:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim number As Int32 = New Random().[Next]()
Console.WriteLine(number)

Dim GenerateRandom As Func(Of Int32) = Function() New Random().[Next]()

Console.WriteLine("Begin Call")
GenerateRandom.DoAsync(Function(number) Console.WriteLine(number))
Console.WriteLine("End Call")
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres' a translation.

```
Dim random = New Random()
Dim number = random.Next()
Console.WriteLine(number)

Dim GenerateRandom = Function ()
    Dim random = New Random()
    Dim number = random.Next()
  End Function

Console.WriteLine("Begin Call")
GenerateRandom.DoAsync(Sub (number) Console.WriteLine(number))
Console.WriteLine("End Call")
```

Comment: 'function' needs to be 'function()'

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick code conversion from http://converter.telerik.com/.  I tested it and it seems to work.

```
Dim number As Int32 = New Random().[Next]()
Console.WriteLine(number)

Dim GenerateRandom As Func(Of Int32) = Function() New Random().[Next]()

Console.WriteLine("Begin Call")
GenerateRandom.DoAsync(Function(number) Console.WriteLine(number))
Console.WriteLine("End Call")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is an easy and free way to convert between .NET languages.

Comment: Not when it comes to lambda expressions.